# How to aggregate multiple task results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I created 2 Tasks in below code snipet, now I would like to club both tasks results into a single variable:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoProcessing()
    {
        List<DataPoint> dp = new List<DataPoint>();

        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process1(dp));
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process2(dp));

        Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

        //var finalResult = task1 result + Task 2 results
    }

    private List<DataPoint> Process1(List<DataPoint> dp1)
    {
        return dp1;
    }
    private List<DataPoint> Process2(List<DataPoint> dp2)
    {
        return dp2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already asked another question about this.  Why are you still intent on using `Task.WhenAll` without the `await` keyword.  That's not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: yes, I understand that I need to use await/async, Thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to join those two lists, you'll first need to mark your method as `async Task`, and then `await Task.WhenAll` in order to asynchronously wait for both tasks to complete:

```
public async Task DoProcessingAsync()
{
    var task1 = Task.Run(Process1);
    var task2 = Task.Run(Process2);

    var result = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    var finalResult = task1.Result.Concat(task2.Result).ToList();
}

private List<DataPoint> Process1()
{
    return new List<DataPoint>();
}

private List<DataPoint> Process2()
{
    return new List<DataPoint>();
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.5 or above, prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Also, `List<T>` isn't thread safe, don't pass a list to be returned by the `ProcessX` method inside your task. Make each return a fresh `List<DataPoint>` so you won't have threading issues.

Comment: dotnetcore must have changed Task. I am getting `'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @KevinBurton I know this is an old comment, but still can be useful for someone: you need to add <TResult> to the task declaration (Task<int> for example), then completed tasks will have access to Result property.

Answer (score 5):

This could be simplified even further as the `await Task.WhenAll` aggregates the results :-

```
Task<int> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return 1; });
Task<int> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return 2; });

var result = await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

// result
// int[2] { 1, 2 }
```